# Perl5 formline round down the exact value 0.5 not round up

Tags: perl, rounding

I have noticed that the formline method in Perl 5 have some strange action.
If the decimal value greater than 0.5, it will round up. 
If the decimal value less than 0.5, it will round down.
But when the decimal value is exact 0.5, we normally should round up but the formline round down the value.

Does anyone know if that is a bug or predesinged? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of a concrete demonstration, I shall point out the two likely culprits:

1. "We normally should round up" is absolutely false. There are many different rounding system. `sprintf`, for example, uses round-to-even.

   ```
   $ perl -E'say sprintf "%1\$.1f => %1\$.0f", $_ for 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5'
   3.5 => 4
   4.5 => 4
   5.5 => 6
   6.5 => 6
   ```
2. The number you think has a fractional component of 5/10 doesn't actually due to floating-point precision error.

   Many numbers are periodic in binary, and periodic numbers cannot accurately be stored as floating numbers. For example, 1/10, 2/10, 3/10, 4/10, 6/10, 7/10, 8/10 and 9/10 are all periodic in binary just like 1/3 is periodic in decimal (and binary).

   5/10 is actually easy to store as a floating point number (5/10 = 1/2 = 2<sup>-1</sup>), but if you obtained the number through arithmetic, you might not actually have 5/10.

   ```
   $ perl -E'$x += 0.01 for 1..50; say sprintf "%.40f", $x'
   0.5000000000000002220446049250313080847263
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.
With a small test that I found that the formline is also uses round-to-even.
Thank you!

Comment: Please help to check below test code and help answer if there is any way that we can control what rounding method to use. Thanks.
`#!/usr/bin/perl

my $format='@#######';
my $var1='15334.5000';
my $var2='15334.50001';
my $var3='15335.5000';
my $var4='15336.5000';
formline $format, $var1;
print "var1=$^A\n";
$^A='';
formline $format, $var2;
print "var2=$^A\n";
$^A='';
formline $format, $var3;
print "var3=$^A\n";
$^A='';
formline $format, $var4;
print "var4=$^A\n";
`

Comment: You could round the value before passing it to the form